# Scrapy: How to Execute Parsing Incrementally Instead of Waiting for a Loop to Complete?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have the following Scrapy parser:

```
def parse_letter(self, response):
    oid_paths = [
        i.extract() for i in response.xpath("//*[@class='list-item']/a/@href")
    ]

    for oid_path in oid_paths:
        segments = oid_path.strip("/").split("/")
        oid = segments[-1].replace("-", "+")

        meta_data = {"oid": oid}

        oid_urls = []
        offset = 0
        while True:
            api_response = requests.get(
                self.api.format(oid=oid, offset=offset)
            )

            if api_response.status_code != 200:
                break

            api_response = api_response.json()

            if len(api_response) == 0:
                break
            actress_urls.extend(api_response)
            offset += 20


        for oid_url in oid_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                oid_url,  # Use the full URL
                callback=self.parse_oid,
                meta=meta_data,
            )
```

As you can see, I make API calls and obtain all the URLs that I want to be processed in parse_model. However, before `parse_oid` gets executed, it waits for the main for loop to complete. Shouldn't it start processing the parsing as it's called?

Thanks

Comment: No... why would it do that?  You are using the requests lib to get the oid urls which is not asynchronous